# conditions inside conditions pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

below is my DF in which I want to create a column based on other columns

```
test = pd.DataFrame({"Year_2017" : [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 4], "Year_2018" : [np.nan, np.nan, 3, np.nan], "Year_2019" : [np.nan, 2, np.nan, np.nan], "Year_2020" : [1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})

    Year_2017   Year_2018   Year_2019   Year_2020
0       NaN         NaN         NaN          1
1       NaN         NaN          2          NaN
2       NaN          3          NaN         NaN
3        4          NaN         NaN         NaN
```

The aim will be to create a new column and take value of the columns which is notna()

Below is what I tried without success..

```
test['Final'] = np.where(test.Year_2017.isna(), test.Year_2018,
                              np.where(test.Year_2018.isna(), test.Year_2019,
                                      np.where(test.Year_2019.isna(), test.Year_2020, test.Year_2019)))

     Year_2017  Year_2018   Year_2019   Year_2020   Final
0      NaN        NaN          NaN          1       NaN
1      NaN        NaN           2          NaN      NaN
2      NaN         3           NaN         NaN       3
3       4         NaN          NaN         NaN      NaN
```

The expected output:

```
     Year_2017  Year_2018   Year_2019   Year_2020   Final
0      NaN        NaN          NaN          1        1
1      NaN        NaN           2          NaN       2
2      NaN         3           NaN         NaN       3
3       4         NaN          NaN         NaN       4
```

Comment: Whats happen if there is multiple non NaN per row?

Comment: I don't need them, I drop them. Besides, I forgot to mention the columns are "object" and not int llike in the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can forward or back filling missing values and then select last or first column:

```
test['Final'] = test.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]
```

---

```
test['Final'] = test.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
```

If there is only one non missing values per rows and numeric use:

```
test['Final'] = test.min(1)
test['Final'] = test.max(1)
test['Final'] = test.mean(1)
test['Final'] = test.sum(1, min_count=1)
```

Comment: is it possible to select a subset of columns to apply? for eg, I have a df with 80 columns, how can I specify for which column apply this function?

Comment: @Annis15 - Do you need first 80 columns? then use `test['Final'] = test.iloc[:, :80].ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]`

Comment: only col from 5 to 8

Comment: @Annis15 - So change `test.iloc[:, :80]` to `test.iloc[:, 5:8]`, it is selected 5,6,7,8th columns

Answer (score 1):

I you only have a single non NA value per row, you can use:

```
df['Final'] = test.max(axis=1)
```

(or other aggregators)